# Object method call VS class method call. Best practice?

Tags: php, oop

I am writing an app in PHP and I have gathered a collection of miscellaneous functions inside a class that I am calling toolbox

```
Class toolbox {
  public function misc($var) {
    return do_something($var);
  } 
}
```

I am loading the toolbox inside my various scripts and then using it, but I am not sure what the best practice should be...

Option 1: object method call

```
__construct() {
  require_once('toolbox.php');
  $this->ToolBox = new toolbox;
}

some_function($input){
  return $this->ToolBox->misc($input);
}
```

Option 2: class method call

```
__construct() {
  require_once('toolbox.php');
}

some_function($input){
  return ToolBox::misc($input);
}
```

Is there some kind of best practice about that? I don't think that I need various instances of the toolbox.

Comment: Consider putting them as free functions in a separate namespace.

Comment: @DCoder Why did you offer that solution as a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @Homezar, probably, because he/she is not aiming for cheap reputation. But DCoder is completely correct - the best practice for random function is to place them in a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make them static functions.**

```
class Toolbox {
    static public function Tool1(){
    }
}
Toolbox::Tool1(); // Call the static method without instantiating the object
```

**Why static classes and not namespaces?**

**Because static utility classes tend to grow and tend to be many.** You might have one for **files**, **strings**, **arrays**, ... etc. Each of them can easily jump 5K lines or even more. **But do you always use them?** NO! They might be used in 5% of the pages on your site. So why include them in the first place?

[**PHP's Autoload^**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) **comes to our aid here**. But **autoload only works with classes** while **namespaces have to be included**. You have three choices now:

- you `include` / `require` EVERYTHING so you make sure your namespaces are always accessible but you force PHP to parse a lot of files on each run plus you get the inherent performance penalty of actually `including` / `requiring` a file
- you keep `include_once` / `require_once` in each `.php` file where you use your utility classes
- you use the `spl_autoload_register` and forget about dependencies while the autoloader does the heavy lifting in the background for you

**First two can work with namespaces while the last needs a static class**. When your code base grows A LOT you start appreciating `autoload` and you start appreciating static classes no matter what OTHERS tell you. So:

```
best practices == guidelines && best practices != mandatory practices
best practices != what works best in your specific scenario
```

^ **prepare for the negative votes now** :)