# Adding custom Util classes where and how?

Tags: php, fuelphp

Where and how should add custom classes like class Util with some static functions an ? 
And how to add these to autoloader ?

Comment: **You just said the word `static`.** You will now feel the wrath of SO OOP purists like I did [**here^**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493608/object-method-call-vs-class-method-call-best-practice/17493725). *Brace yourself!*

Comment: Well in views it's better to use static functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom classes should be in: **app/classes/**

So, in your case, the path should be: **app/classes/util.php**

```
class Util
{
    public static function foo()
    {
        /* foo() implementation */
    }
}
```

Nothing has to be added to the autoloader, you only have to call the class method you want:

```
\Util::foo();
```

That's it!